# relocating documents folder of ios applications

Tags: ios, jailbreak, symlink

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4s with iOS 5.1.1. One of the things that always bothers me is that apps can't share files with each other. 
So I thought I can circumvent that behavior by creating a symlink to a folder in /var/mobile/.

For my first try I used the Dolphin Browser from the AppStore (since you can download nearly everything with it). I renamed the original Documents folder in the apps folder and created a symbolic link to /var/mobile/SharedDocs.
Apparently that doesn't work. Trying to download something simply fails in Dolphin.

Long story short: 
Did anyone else try something similar with success?
Any other ideas I can try?
Do I need to program some kind of mobilesubstrate extention?

This is my first post here and I'm sorry if I did something wrong ;)

Greetings
JunkiXL

P.S. Actually I didn't replace the Documents folder but the Downloads folder. Here are the full pathes to the directories:
- Original Download Folder: /var/mobile/Applications/734.../Documents/Downloads
-> renamed that folder for backup purpose.
- created a link with "ln -s /var/mobile/SharedDocs Downloads" in /var/mobile/Applications/734.../Documents

Comment: Which folder did you **rename** (can you provide the full path)?  Is it the Dolphin Browser's `Documents` folder?  Please show the link (which is the *target* of the link).

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I don't think this question should have been migrated to wherever the hell this is.  The line *"Do I need to program some kind of mobilesubstrate extention?"* should have identified that it was a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access other folders beyond the sandbox from App Store applications.

There is a library in Cydia called [Unbox](http://planet-iphones.com/cydia/id/org.h2co3.unbox) that allows you to access the filesystem from a sandboxed application but you will need to create your own app to achieve this as it is NOT A TWEAK.

For Information, Sandboxing is Apple's security feature preventing App Store applications from accessing the whole filesystem and also limiting what API's can be used. Some private API's can, others will simply crash if run in the Sandbox.